# How to create hierarchical JSON from API in AngularJs and MySQL

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to output a structured JSON from a query to my API. I have the following 2 tables (MySQL):

```
**TABLE1:**

uid
name
pptw

**TABLE2**

id
table1_uid
assignment
start_time
end_time
date
comments
```

And this is the JSON output I am looking for:

```
$scope.table1 = {
    "toplevel":
        [
           {
             "uid": 1,
             "name": "john",
             "pptw": "ATWF",
             "child":
                 {
                   "id": 1,
                   "table1_uid": 1,
                   "assignment": null,
                   "start_time": "14:53:00",
                   "end_time":  "15:00:00",
                   "date": null,
                   "comments": null
                 }
           }, 
           {
             "uid": 22,
             "name": "carol",
             "pptw": "DWFF",
             "child":
                 {
                   "id": 2,
                   "table1_uid": 22,
                   "assignment": null,
                   "start_time": "11:00:00",
                   "end_time":  "14:00:00",
                   "date": null,
                   "comments": "Completed"
                 }
            }
        ]
      }
```

I have a promise as follow:

```
var request = $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: '.../api/v1/ppp',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                params: {
                    //record_uid: record_uid,
                }
            })
              .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  deferred.resolve(data);
              })
              .error(function (data, status) {
                  deferred.reject();
              });

            return deferred.promise;
```

And on the database, I have the following query:

```
SELECT tb1.uid
    tb1.name
    tb1.pptw,
    tb2.id,
    tb2.table1_uid,
    tb2.assignment,
    tb2.start_time,
    tb2.end_time,
    tb2.date,
    tb2.comments
FROM 
    table1 tb1, table2 tb2
WHERE 
    tb1.uid = tb2.table1_uid
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve this, thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly means, there's no backend api specified. Do you want the server side method to create the json structure or client side method?

Comment: Thanks Kiran  LM for your reply. I though the question was pretty clear. My question was "How to create hierarchical JSON from API in AngularJs and MySQL", that implies that I am creating the JSON on the client side using AngularJs. Therefore, any backend API is not relevant here. I posted the answer to my question below but appreciate you took the time to reply my post thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my questions, I managed to figure out how to do it. I hope it helps someone else trying to do the same thing as I did.

Here is how to create the hierarchical JSON:

```
var results_tree_header = [];
var results_tree = [];

if (result.rows.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {


results_tree.push({
             "uid": result.rows.item(i).uid,
             "name": result.rows.item(i).name,
             "pptw": result.rows.item(i).pptw,
             "child":
                 {
                   "id": result.rows.item(i).id,
                   "table1_uid": result.rows.item(i).table1_uid,
                   "assignment": result.rows.item(i).assignment,
                   "start_time": result.rows.item(i).start_time,
                   "end_time":  result.rows.item(i).end_time,
                   "date": result.rows.item(i).date,
                   "comments": result.rows.item(i).comments
                 }
           }); 

results_tree_header = { toplevel: results_tree };

    }
}
```